# Sphinx anchor defined twice (singlehtml output)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a sphinx project which uses figures and footnotes. I noticed that as soon as I include a caption in figures, the `id`s rendered in HTML are defined twice.

For example, consider a minimal project like this:

```
Project Example
===============
this is index.rst

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   inc

hello [#0]_ world: 

We should expect that footnote 0 [#1]_ would have `id1`, and  footnote 2 `id2`

.. [#0] Lorem Impsum.
.. [#1] Lorem Impsum.
```

And `inc.rst`:

```
Included
========

.. figure:: _static/cat.jpg
   :scale: 20%
   :align: center

   This is a caption
```

Running `sphinx-build -M singlehtml "." "_build"` renders:

```
<span id="document-inc"></span><section id="included">
<h2>Included<a class="headerlink" href="#included" title="Permalink to this headline">¶</a></h2>
<figure class="align-center" id="id1">
<a ...></a>
<figcaption>
<p><span class="caption-text">This is a caption</span><a class="headerlink" href="#id1" title="Permalink to this image">¶</a></p>
</figcaption>
</figure>
</section>
</div>
<p>We should expect that operator <a class="footnote-reference brackets" href="#id3" id="id1">2</a> would:</p>
<p>We should expect that operator <a class="footnote-reference brackets" href="#id4" id="id2">3</a> would:</p>
<dl class="footnote brackets">
<dt class="label" id="id3"><span class="brackets"><a class="fn-backref" href="#id1">2</a></span></dt>
<dd><p>Lorem Impsum.</p>
</dd>
<dt class="label" id="id4"><span class="brackets"><a class="fn-backref" href="#id2">3</a></span></dt>
<dd><p>Lorem Impsum.</p>
</dd>
</dl>
```

If I remove the caption, the figure opening HTML is rendered without `id="id1"`, like this:

```
<figure class="align-center">
```

Is this a bug in sphinx?
Can I tell sphinx `use the following id in figure` to avoid collisions?

Comment: Probably a bug, see [Sphinx issue #4814](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4814).

Comment: Darn, it's an old bug... I guess it's a low prio...