# Is there a way to disable automatic anchors for Sphinx headings/sections?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a use case where I do not want Sphinx to automatically generate anchors for my sections because I have multiple sections with the same title.

```
Title
-----

sample text

Title
-----

more sample text
```

With the default Sphinx project configurations this will result in conflicts in anchors and references, and I don't want that for now. Is there a specific config/build option to disable anchor generation for sections?

Comment: When I `make html` with that sample, I get `#title` for the first anchor and `#id1` for the second. I don't see a conflict. Do you have an extension configured that causes conflicts? Finally you could use [`ref`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-ref) to disambiguate anchor headings.

Comment: Are you using the `singlehtml` builder? Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/70980424/407651 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/70543599/407651

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no configuration option to suppress the generation of these [implicit hyperlink targets](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#implicit-hyperlink-targets).

You can, however, prevent the conflict providing an "explicit" hyperlink target, e.g.,

```
.. _title:

Title
-----

sample text

Title
-----

Sample text referencing the first title_.
```

(Tested with plain Docutils, the mileage with Sphinx may vary.)